# Exactly how many users can Support Blazeds Messeging service ? for much user support what we need to do(pooling)?

Tags: flex3, air, blazeds

I designed one On line Trading Application, which uses blazeds & jetty,
in that i used AMF-LongPooling as channel, with following parameter,

Here is the problem is Each message is not reaching all the user,who are connected, messages are missing to few users (300 recieving out of 600)...

what we need to do to provided instant messages to all Online. ??

Please help me one?

Comment: Anybody is there for me?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is too generic, it's not possible to give an answer because it depends on too many things: network, size of the messages, your system architecture etc. My suggestion is to invest heavily in reading BlazeDS developer guide and to turn the debug messages on (there is a lot of useful information displayed by BlazeDS). It would also help to study BlazeDS source code.

Comment: Hi Cornetl Creanga, U might be right, but i suppose blazeds is not allowing more than 200 or some n number of request from all request(Subcribers), i wud like to know weather blazeds is not support for unlimited user access or problem with my publisher-Subcriber model ?

Comment: There is no hard limit in BlazeDS, theoretically it can support a very large number of concurrent users. However the servlet container can have a limit (the maximum number of open threads).

Comment: Then most of the messeges are not delivered, when 600+ users are subcribing

Answer (score 0):

In case of AMF-longpolling the request is parked on the server and if too many requests are parked at a time, they will consume all available threads for the server. And the next client won't be able to connect.

In your case I am assuming the message size is not very big. And the solution can be one of the followings:

1. To increase the number of available threads. For that you can have multiple server instances and distribute your clients over them.
2. You can make use of LCDS.

You don't get that problem in LCDS as it makes use of NIO end points that don't block the thread. I have come to know that this thread restriction is not a problem with Servlet 3.0 and in that case you can support more clients with blazeds itself. You can check more about it [HERE](http://blog.hiraash.org/2012/04/13/scaling-blazeds-with-servlet-3-concurrency/#comment-170).